# Find matched strings in two files

Tags: bash

I have two files like this:

File_A:

```
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

File_B:

```
1 D
2 B
3 C
```

So what I want to do is find the matched rows based on column 2 and get a new file. Both of the files have a header line

Comment: Wich one is row? which one is column?

Comment: sorry I updated the question

Comment: Hi drmaly, do you know that in File_B you separate with a single space, while it is a double space in File_A? I guess that is not on purpose? Furthermore, you mention bash as a tag, which means that is the only solution you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
while read line; do grep "${line##* }" File_B; done < File_A > File_C
```